# How to Add margins above and below a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-listfragment

I've been struggling to do something that I imagine is a pretty common request for the android ListView, in my specific case this ListView is being used as part of a ListFragment.

I would like a blank padded area above and below my list that gets scrolled up and down along with the list items when the list is interacted with.

I've done a lot of looking around and not only have I been unable to find an answer I've also found next to no-one asking the question, makes me wonder if I've missed something.

My first attempt has been to the following:

```
 <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:paddingTop="16dip"
    android:paddingBottom="16dip"
    android:clipToPadding="false"...
```

This provides the required padding but unfortunately the "clipToPadding" property doesn't do what it says on the tin, when scrolling the list the items are clipped off 16dip from the top and bottom of the ListView's visible region, not what I'm looking for. Any idea why it is still being clipped?

My second attempt involves the programmatically adding transparent header and footer views to the list via the ListView api:

```
addHeaderView();
addFooterView();
```

This works beautifully and gives me the exact interaction that I am looking for. Unfortunately it falls apart when my fragment comes out of the back stack. The old header and footer views are gone, discarded with the rest of the view when my fragment was pushed into the back stack but if I try and add new ones I receive an error stating that the list adapter has already been set. Header/footer views can only be set prior to the setting of the adapter which unfortunately happened an entire component lifecycle loop ago.

The only "solutions" I have seen to that error is to null the list adapter, re-add my footer/header and then set the list adapter to it's original value. This screams "hack" to me and makes me think I'm just not using it right in the first place.

Is there any way to get the desired functionality working in a sensible way? Is extending ListFragment part of my problem? Would I be better off rolling my own fragment composed of a ListView?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="95dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="95dip"

Comment: I haven't really looked into why your first two approaches don't appear to work, but a third, pretty straightforward one would be to supply a top-padded layout for the first list item in the adapter and a bottom-padded layout for the last. Just a thought in case you're not able to make progress with the alternatives.

Comment: Where are you inserting the `addHeaderView()` and `addFooterView()` methods? I would insert them in the `onStart()` method to be populated even after a back stack takes place.